# font css showing bold where font style normal, but only on certain pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've put together a wordpress website and the client is reporting that the main navigation font is bold on all pages except the contact page.

I can't replicate the behaviour but she's sent me the screenshots to show what's happening. She's using Safari Version 5.1.5.

So I guess I'm looking for feedback on any errors in my code that I've overlooked and if there's a logical reason that she's seeing this.

Here's the url: http://www.elevatevitality.com.au

Appreciate any feedback or assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out Safari 5.1.5 and didn't see any bold body copy. It may be a setting on her particular machine, but you can always try to set your global `font-weight: normal;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, gave it a shot and still not working on the clients side. It looks like it could be something on her local setup.

Comment: If you can't replicate it on multiple machines, that's the only thing it could be. If you are setting the styles to specifically tell the browser to be a normal font-weight, the only thing that could be over-writing it is her preferences. I'm guessing she's not so techie? Maybe suggesting she restore her defaults would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#mainNav {
    margin-top: 125px;
}

nav#menu ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53px;
}

nav#menu ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #386c65;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 300;       /* try this */
}

nav#menu ul li a {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #DCB215;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 300;       /* try this */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, gave it a shot and still not working on the clients side. It looks like it could be something on her local setup.